# How to determine the used/available memory on AIX with a non root user?

Tags: aix, memory-usage

Using a non root user what is the recommended method to determine the global system used/available memory on an AIX system ?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [topas(1)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/topas.htm) or [vmstat(1)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds6/vmstat.htm).